# C++ assign map different classes

Tags: c++, oop, typedef, stdmap

At the moment I having following problem:
I want to assign an object of a class too a map struct

My goal is:
If I call the map with the ids inside the brackets, the function must be start!

I know the following approach doesn't work. But I would be very nice, I someone can give me an idea or a tip how I can realize this approach...

Here is an example:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class start {
    public:
        void sayhello() {
            std::cout << "Hallo!!" << std::endl;
        }
};

class end {
    public:
        void saybye() {
            std::cout << "Bye!" << std::endl;
        }
}


typedef void (*method)(void);


int main() {

    std::map<int, std::map<int, std::map<int, method>>> myMap;
    myMap[1][5][10] = start::sayhello;
    myMap[2][1][20] = end::saybye;

    // // usage:
    myMap[1][5][10]();
    myMap[2][1][20]();
}
```

Thank you very much for your support! <3

Comment: You could hold `std::function`s in your map.

Comment: You assign 'oop' tag. Probably solution should be TOTALLY diferent designed in OOP. But what is real problem? (map of refferences, derriving classes, but hard to guess what U want).  Today attempt is totally out of Object Oriented Programming

Answer (score 0):

Normally a member function is called from a instance of its class:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    void fun() {.....};
};

//somewhere in your code
Bar b;
b.fun();
```

The good news is that you can avoid the class instance by making the function **static**

```
class Bar
{
public:
    static void fun() {.....};
};

//somewhere in your code
Bar::fun();
```

Comment: thanks! But how can I insert different static functions inside the std::map?

Comment: Just type **static** before your two functions. And correct a typo: add a `;` at the the end of `end`class.

Comment: but when I use static, I must create an instance of the class. Is there no direct solution available? To create an instance inside of the map?

Comment: @N.Men The point of "static" is that you avoid instancing. See Shrikanth's answer, he has fixed your code and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Code in the current form will not work.

Two approaches available:

1. Declare it simply as a function and not a member function inside a class.
2. Declare the member function as a static function.

Code for the 2nd approach is given below:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class start {
    public:
        static void sayhello() {
            std::cout << "Hallo!!" << std::endl;
        }
};

class end {
    public:
        static void saybye() {
            std::cout << "Bye!" << std::endl;
        }
};


typedef void (*method)(void);


int main() {

    std::map<int, std::map<int, std::map<int, method>>> myMap;
    myMap[1][5][10] = start::sayhello;
    myMap[2][1][20] = end::saybye;

    // // usage:
    myMap[1][5][10]();
    myMap[2][1][20]();
    return 0;
}
```