# C++ std::vector assign methods

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, c++17

has anyone an idea how I can realize this with working code? 
My wish is to fill a vector with executable methods of a class...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <any>

class foo {
    public:
        void boo() {
            std::cout << "WM 2018" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::any> vec;
    vec.push_back( (new foo)->boo() );

    vec[0]();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to have them? Possible XY problem.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085852/c-assign-map-different-classes) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> vec{[](){ foo{}.boo();}};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/GKiLNl)